# How to destroy Cloudinary Product Gallery using the VueJS2 beforedestroy() hook?

Tags: vuejs2, cloudinary

Need some guidance on how to property destroy a widget and remove it from memory when user navigates away to another page.

I have a method that loads a widget like so on a component's mounted() hook:

`Widget.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="myGallery"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.loadWidget()
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    ......???
  },
  methods: {
    loadWidget() {
      const myGallery = window.cloudinary.galleryWidget({
        container: '#myGallery',
        cloudName: 'XXXX',
        mediaAssets: [
          {
            publicId:
              'pic.jpg'
          }
        ]
      })
      myGallery.render()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The widget's doc says I can use the following method to erase the widget from memory:
`myGallery.destroy();`

How would I do that here in the code? Do I need to make another instance of the widget and then append the `.destroy()` method to it? I don't understand.

Comment: change `const myGallery = ...` to `this._gallery=...`. Then in `beforeDestroy`, you can call `this._gallery.destroy();`

Comment: So in `loadWidget() method, copy the instance to vue data property and then destroy it using that ?

Comment: why the underscore?

Comment: yea, dont declare a data property, just assign to a `this._variable` otherwise Vue will try to make it observable and mess up. underscore is just a convention, indicating it is not a normal data property, just a private field.

Comment: well that is interesting, never thought you could use a `this` like that. I suppose this works, thanks!